# Magento - get product collection of all products

Tags: php, magento, collections, categories, product

I need a custom product collection of all products. Currently there are no categories which contain all products of the store (as there are 8000 products we can not add them in to one extra category).

What I need is on a particular CMS page the product collection of all products is displayed. 
So far I have a CMS page with the block:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

I have created an module to override 'Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List'

I believe the function I need to edit would be 'protected function _getProductCollection()'

As we can see in the block call theres no category specified. What I need is in the overidden _getProductCollection function is all products in the store returned.

Is there any way this can be achieved?

Comment: Do you actually need a product collection of all products, or do you just need to display all products on one page and the route you're attempting is a product collection?

Comment: I need to first get all of the products for the website then filter it further so only products with a certain attribute value are shown. As the products are across multiple categories I thought I would first get all products in the product collection then filter it further, so it displays similar to list.phtml view.

Comment: Bad idea, this will make your site very slow. You should use the product collection but *first* `addAttributeToFilter()` and *then* `load()`.

Answer (score 14):

**There are several ways you can get the list of products from a store.**
Try this way :

```
<?php
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->load();
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){
   echo $_product->getId().'</br>';
   echo $_product->getName().'</br>';
   echo $_product->getProductUrl().'</br>';
   echo $_product->getPrice().'</br>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't override the List block, this will have an effect on the real product listing pages.

The simple way to to copy the file to the local namespace and rename it:

from:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php
```

to:

```
app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Fulllist.php
```

You can then use your new block without having to make a full module, and it will mean your List block will work the same and not break anything on your store.

You can then safely modify the as required:

```
/**
 * Retrieve loaded category collection
 *
 * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
 */
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

    // this now has all products in a collection, you can add filters as needed.

    //$collection
    //    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    //    ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_name', array('eq' => 'value'))
    //    ->addAttributeToFilter('another_name', array('in' => array(1,3,4)))
    //;

    // Optionally filter as above..

    return $collection;
}
```

You can then use your new block like so:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_fulllist" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have followed your instructions and added the new block. However when I i run the body of the code, I get nothing displayed (my footer disappears to suggest a stop in the php).

Comment: Can you modify your index.php file to enable DeveloperMode(true) and display_errors = 1, this will give you a better error message

Comment: I have tried the code if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
} and ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1); on my index file but am still not getting error messages.

Comment: comment out the 'if' wrapped around Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); so it is always executed

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried that also but I'm not getting any error messages still. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you still got your block overrideing the original List.php block? that could cause an issue..

Comment: I disabled this and removed the files I created from the server. The problem still persists. I'm only using the code you provided me with.

Comment: and you copied over the original List.php file, and then modified only that methods I outlined?

Comment: you will also need to chang the class name though, from 'Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List to 'Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Fulllist to reflect the name change

Comment: I have all these changed but the same problem persists. If I leave the original function code in it gives an no matching products message but when I try to use the custom collection it doesn't work.

Comment: opps I had a typo in the paths, did you copy them to the incorrect location I had? I've updated it now, forgot to add 'Catalog'

Comment: I did but I realized that as well and had them already changed. Only a guess but could not specifying an category in the block could that cause a problem?

Comment: The problem is probably caused inside the view file then, i'll check a working example for you when I get home. You could try and make a new view file, copy and rename list.phtml and then strip most of it out and dump out the products

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will try creating a new list.phtml first.