# Magento - Add 301 redirect for all products (approximately 6000 products)

Tags: php, magento, redirect, http-status-code-301

I want to add product category in the URL of the product and add 301 redirect from old URL (without category) to new URL (with category) for a Magento site.
There are nearly 6000 products with 30 different categories, which makes it impossible to add all redirects in .htaccess. 
**Here is and example for what I'm trying to do-**
OLD URL looks like - http://domainname.com/product-name.html 
NEW URL will look like - http://domainname.com/category/product-name.html 
It's easy to configure the URL, but I want to add 301 redirect for SEO purpose.
 So that, if anyone hits old URL - http://domainname.com/product-name.html in search results, then he should get redirected to http://domainname.com/category/product-name.html 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom script and you can add custom rewrite magento

1. Get all product collection programmatically ([Magento - get product collection of all products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087798/magento-get-product-collection-of-all-products))
2. Add magento core/url_rewrite table (https://gist.github.com/byjujohn/5508233)